# If $f \ge 0$ is Riemann integrable on$[a,b]$, with $\int^a_b f =0$ how to show that there must be some $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

it is also given that $f(t)\geq 0$ for all $t$ .I'm supposed to first prove that $\exists[c,d]\subseteq[a,b]$ s.t. $f(t)<\varepsilon\forall t\in[c,d],\implies\int^d_c f =0 $. Which I'm struggling to do.

By definition, let $\varepsilon>0$ then $\exists\delta$ s.t.
$$ \left| R(f,P)-\int^b_a f \right| <\varepsilon$$
where $P$ is $\delta$-fine. Note that $R(f,P)$ here denotes the Riemann sum. Suppose $f$ is Riemann integrable, then
$$ \left| R(f,P)-0\right| =|R(f,P)|<\varepsilon$$
$$=\left|\sum^n_{k=1}f(t_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})\right|<\varepsilon$$
then because $x_k>0\forall k$
$$\text{Riemann sum of $f$ from $c,d$ }<\left|\sum^n_{k=1}f(t_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})\right|<\varepsilon$$

but I'm not sure how that implies that $f(t)<\varepsilon$

Comment: That is easy if one uses the fact that every Riemann-integrable function is continuous at some points (actually, it's continuous at almost every point). Can you use that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos We've covered that all continuous functions are Riemann Integrable, but I thought the converse isn't necessarily true? (Riemann Integrable $\not\implies$ continuity)

Comment: I did **not** claim that every Riemann-integrable function is continuous, only that it is continuous at some points of its domain.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I see that this is Lebesgue's Criterion for integrablility, but I'm not sure how this helps. I suppose if $f$ takes on every positive value at some point, then we can "zoom in" to a small enough subinterval such that $f(t)<\varepsilon$, but we dont know that it does, right? Sorry I'm not seeing what to do here.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)>0$, take $\delta>0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{f(x_0)}2$, which implies that $|f(x)>\frac{f(x_0)}2$. But then$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx>\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\geqslant2\delta\frac{f(x_0)}2>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can go by contradiction which seems simpler. i.e., assume that there exists $\epsilon'>0$ such that every sub interval $[\alpha,\beta]\subset [a,b]$ has a point $x_{\alpha,\beta}\in [\alpha,\beta]$ satisfying

$$ f(x_{\alpha,\beta})\geq \epsilon' .$$

Then, you obtain that the upper Darboux sum of any partition $P$ will have to satisfy that

$$ U(P,f)\geq \epsilon'\cdot(b-a). $$

You know that

$$ \overline{\int_a^b} f(x)dx= \inf_{P\in \mathcal{P}[a,b]} U(P,f)\geq \epsilon' \cdot (b-a)>0 .$$

If you prefer to work with Riemann sums instead, you can argue that for any partition  $P$, there is a Riemann sum corresponding to $P$ satisfying

$$R(f;P)\geq \epsilon'\cdot (b-a), $$
and obtain a contradiction in a similar manner.

Comment: How does the upper integral contradict the assumption?

Comment: @jeb2 Since $f$ is integrable, $\overline{\int}_a^bf=\int_a^b f$, while we know that $\int_a^b f=0$.